# In an array, checking if Strings are the same, if so count up

Tags: java

```
String[] testing = new String[]{"Hat", "Cat", "Bear", "Tiger", "Bird"};
```

Using the array above and **generating it in a random order**, I'm trying to check each String to the other, and if any are the same, then checking goes up by 1.

Ex: if testing[0] == testing[1], checking++, if not, test[0] == test[2] and so on.

However, I'm just not getting my logic right as its giving me random integers that I'm not expecting. If anyone can point out my errors id appreciate it.

Note: I'm new to Java and do not know a lot of methods out there.

```
    public int checkUp() {
        int checking = 0;
        int looper = 0;
        int checker = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < testing.length; i++) {
            while (checker < testing.length) {
                if (String.valueOf(testing[looper]).equals(String.valueOf(testing[i]))) {  
                    checker++;
                } else {
                    looper++;
                }
                checker++;
            }
        }
        return checking;
    }
```

Comment: You `return checking;` but you never do anything with that variable beside initializing it with `int checking = 0;`. So I'm surprised you say you are getting "random integers" when all you should ever get returned from that method is a very non-random `0`

Comment: I would use two for-loops inside another: `for (int i...) { for (int j...) { if (testing[i] is equal to testing[j]) { checking++; } } }`

Comment: `return testing.length - (int) Stream.of(testing).distinct().count();`

Comment: If 3 strings are the same, by how much should the counter be incremented? Is it 2 (because string1 == string2 and string1 == string 3) or is it 3 (string1==string2, string1==string3, string2=string3)?

Comment: @k314159 So all strings dont match then 0, if string1 == string 2 or string1== string etc then its 1. if string 1 == string 2 && string 1== string 3 then 2. if all strings match then output is 4. I hope this helps b/c im still having a hard time understanding

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to do this using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html): *Add all elements of your array into a set. Your result is then the difference between the array length and set size.*

Something like this:

```
String[] input = new String[] {"Hat", "Cat", "Bear", "Tiger", "Bird"};
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.toList(input));
int result = input.length - set.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public int checkUp() {
    int looper = 0;
    int checking = 0;
    while (looper < testing.length) {
        int checker = looper + 1;
        while (checker < testing.length) {
            if (testing[looper].equals(testing[checker])) {  
                checking++;    
            }
            checker++;
        }
    }
    return checking;
}
```

This would return the total number of matching strings.
Note : you need not use `String.valueOf` since the elements in the array are already of type `String`